# Does Instant Account Verification work for UK bank accounts yet?

Tags: yodlee

When I looked at IAV last year it only worked in the USA. Is this feature live in the UK yet or is there a date for when it will work with British bank accounts?

Answer (score 0):

IAV is not available for UK sites for now and there is no specific date when it will be available.